# Why is python giving different output from same code

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting a different output from what the YouTube instructor gets,the tutorial was from 4 years ago using python 3

```
num = [5,2,5,2,2]

for x_counts in num:

    output = ''

    for count in range(x_counts):

        output += "x"

        print(output)
```

This code is supposed to generate the same output as the one below

```
numbers = [5,2,5,2,2]

for x in numbers:

    print("x" * x)
```

But I'm getting different output

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: unindent the `print(output)` four spaces

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be related to the indentation in your code, as it's crucial in Python. Make sure that your code is indented correctly!